# My forgotten password strategy - Any showstoppers here?

Tags: php, security, login-script

There's a lot of similar questions, but I didn't see this:

I'm using users eMails for username - since they are unique yet memorable (not shown).
And the send_a_new_random_password for the "retrieval".

BUT, that would allow a disgruntled ex to change a users password again and again : (

To get around this (here it comes) I want to have 2 "correct" passwords in the user-record
- PASSWORD and newPASSWORD (both hashed with PHPass 0.3)

At the next successful login (checking both), I save the used one as PASSWORD, and dump newPASSWORD - Thus rendering the click_this_obscure_URL_to_enable process unnessecary : )

Am I overlooking something ?

Comment: What if I forget both passwords?

Comment: I answered a similar question once, it may apply to this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235441/forgot-password-page-but-passwords-are-hashed/5235514#5235514

Comment: @Pekka: I'll send the new (random) one in an eMail.

Comment: ah, I see, then it's essentially what the answer says that I link to.

Comment: @Pekka: Yes : ) - except I didn't consider a time-restraint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's standard practice to only active the new password if the user clicks a link in the password change email. Your mechanism looks very similar to that. Your mechanism looks largely fine to me.

If you don't want to send out a password in the email(it's unencrypted after all) you need to use the reset link mechanism or use a temporary password the user must change at the next login. But I think for most websites sending out the password in an email is the least of your security worries.

Comment: Pretty much, except I do everything in the login-dialog, eliminating the need for an "obscure link".

Comment: Copy pasting a random password isn't easier than clicking a link. So IMO you gain nothing with your scheme either.

Comment: Yes - no need for the URL. Just my regular login-dialog - which has a captcha-challenge to thwart brute-force attacks.

Comment: But I need to enter the new randomly generated password. And that's more work than clicking a link.

Comment: True, but that's the price you pay for forgetfulness : )

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to not actually reset the password on the account but send a confirmation email containing a reset link. This way only the person with access to the email account could actually perform the reset. (Unless the disgruntled ex can also access the email :P)

Comment: The same thing here, in principle: Go on using the old password (ignoring ex-terror), or use the newly generated one if you actually forgot the old one.